# Generate Video From Images and Audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, photo, video-editing

I have a list of images: `1.png, 2.png...` and a list of audio files `1.mp3, 2.mp3...`

I'd like to generate a video file where audio clips are concatenated, and each image is displayed over the corresponding audio clip: [image: example image]

Think of the images as slides in a slideshow, and the audio as narration for the slide.

Are there any frameworks which would allow me to do this? I'd like to use FFmpeg CLI or something high level if possible.

Comment: ffmpeg in an iteration on the inputs followed by concatentation can do this.. n.png and n.mp3 are all input to make separate outputs (1,2,3.mp4)  Then a concate step to join these 3 mp4 files.  there are 2 separate sections of ffmpeg docs covering how to combine inputs of static photo with audio and how to concat video files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy method is to make each segment then concatenate with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.png -i 1.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset stillimage -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest 1.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 2.png -i 2.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset stillimage -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest 2.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 2.png -i 2.mp3 -c:v libx264 -preset stillimage -vf format=yuv420p -c:a aac -shortest 2.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

This assumes the image files are the same width & height, and the audio files have the same channel layout & sample rate.

More complicated method is to use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) which allows you to do it all in one command, but you'll have to enter the duration of each image segment to match the corresponding audio duration.